# Is it possible to communicate to an ALB through an internal endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-cost-explorer

**Setup**

We have an ECS cluster with 2 services (called `portal-ECS-service` and `graph-ECS-service`). Each have an ALB (`portal-ALB` and `graph-ALB` respectively).

The setup is this:

`End user <-> portal-ALB <-> portal-ECS-service <-> graph-ALB <-> graph-ECS-service`

**Notes**

- everything is in the same VPC
- `graph-ALB` has `Scheme: internal`
- when communicating from `portal-ECS-service` to `graph-ALB` we use as the endpoint `graph-ALB.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com`

**Problem**

We pay a very large amount (~$50 / day) in `DataTransfer-Out-Bytes`.

**Question**

I've read that high `DataTransfer-Out-Bytes` costs can often be solved by using Internal IP instead of public DNS endpoint.

Is it possible to communicate to an ALB internally without going through the public DNS endpoint? In our case, can we have `portal-ECS-service <-> graph-ALB` communication without paying high `DataTransfer-Out-Bytes` costs?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need external access to the `graph-ALB` you can make the ALB *internal* - then it will only have private IPs.

[image: ELB Internal]

To reduce your data transfer costs even more try to limit the cross-AZ traffic (internal traffic between Availability Zones in the same VPC [costs $0.02/GB](https://www.lastweekinaws.com/blog/aws-cross-az-data-transfer-costs-more-than-aws-says/)). One way is to disable cross-account access in the ALB config:

[image: Cross-AZ ELB]

Check out this for some more discussion: [Why should I ever limit a load balancer to a specific availability zone (AWS)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1022051/why-should-i-ever-limit-a-load-balancer-to-a-specific-availability-zone-aws/1022093#1022093)

Hope that helps :)

Comment: This is very clear, thanks MLu!

One additional note on your answer:
 "With Application Load Balancers, cross-zone load balancing is always enabled." (source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html)